Conda will not deactivate environment for removal
I am trying to remove all traces of an environment so that I can set it up again. Unfortunately, conda thinks that the environment is active no matter how many times I type conda deactivate.
I'm using Windows.
Here's what I have-
(jupyter) H:\>conda deactivate

H:\>conda remove jupyter --all

CondaEnvironmentError: cannot remove current environment. deactivate and run conda remove again


H:\>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\t57731\AppData\Local\miniforge3
2015052                  C:\Users\t57731\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\2015052
2015052-2                C:\Users\t57731\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\2015052-2
2024045                  C:\Users\t57731\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\2024045
2024077                  C:\Users\t57731\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\2024077
20240xx                  C:\Users\t57731\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\20240xx
ccds                     C:\Users\t57731\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\ccds
jupyter                  C:\Users\t57731\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\jupyter
jupyter2                 C:\Users\t57731\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\jupyter2

Similarly, switching to a different environment poses the same issue:
H:\>conda activate base

(base) H:\>conda remove jupyter --all

CondaEnvironmentError: cannot remove current environment. deactivate and run conda remove again


switch to your base environment,  You cannot remove an environment you are using.  conda activate base  then do the remove jupyter call

Same issue. Using a new command prompt...running as admin... no dice.

I would suggest not doing -all then and doing one at a time to see if is it specific to one environment or all of them.

Isn't the '--all' flag is for removing all packages and the environment, not for removing all environments?

conda env remove -n jupyter worked. I thought the syntax was deprecated. Now I realize it was interpreting jupyter as a package name and not an environment name. I think conda remove -n jupyter --all would have worked also. Thank you.

Post it as an answer that you were missing -n

The line conda remove jupyter --all should be conda remove -n jupyter --all.
The -n (or --name) ensures that it's referencing environment name.
